# Can anyone help me figure out how to import this .txt file into my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, repository

I'm working in VS on a repository in Github. I'm importing this `stats.csv` file into my code but the `.readlines()` call isn't printing anything. Does anyone know why? Thank you

Tried many different import methods

```
#this is our main code
import os

cmd = 'curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ksu-is/NFLQuarterbackstatIdentifier/master/stats.csv -o stats.txt'

os.system(cmd)

stats = open('stats.txt', 'a+')
statheadings = stats.readlines()

print(statheadings)
print("123123")
```

Should print the `stats.csv` file lines

Comment: Does the file exist? Does it contain anything? Try the divide-and-conquer approach: is the problem in the downloading, in the `readlines()` method or in the printing? A [mre] will help you to debug this problem, and helps us to focus on the important stuff only (e.g. we can ignore the `curl` command if we know the file is correctly downloaded). Also, your code does not work in Windows while the minimal example maybe does.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and it worked well without 'a+' option when open the text file.
Your code shows nothing because you opened file as a 'wrting' mode.
You should give the option as 'r' or 'r+' or just leave it as default.

> 'r' : open for reading (default)
>
> 'a' : open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists.
>
> '+' : open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)

Try:

```
stats = open('stats.txt')         # select
#stats = open('stats.txt','r')    # one of
#stats = open('stats.txt','r+')   # these
statheadings = stats.readlines()
print(statheadings)
```

It will work as well, and the result: `['404: Not Found\n']`

If you want to check only a value, you can add index also.

Print only the last line:

```
print(satheadings[-1])
```

Result:
`404: Not Found`

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I messed that up.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to save the file to the disk first, you can just open it directly:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ksu-is/NFLQuarterbackstatIdentifier/master/stats.csv')
print(response.text)
```

However, the URL that you're trying to access is giving me a 404. Is this because it's in a private repository? If so, you'll want to store it somewhere where it's publicly accessible so your program can reach it (or otherwise set up a more complicated authentication scheme).